# Find the minimum element of a row of a matrix and its column index for each row

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to find the minimum value of a row of a matrix and its corresponding column. Please run the code below. OptV is the matrix that I would like to create which must give the output of the minimum of each row and its corresponding column index in VAll matrix.

```
    Clear[OptV, V,VAll, NU, EDD, PCP]
    binc = 0.2;
    InitV[cs_, cc_, ED_, P_, NL_, pR_, pW_, b_] = Table[1, {b, 0, 1, binc}];
    V[1] := InitV[cs, cc, ED, P, NL, pR, pW, b];
    NU[cs_, cc_, ED_, P_, NL_, pR_, pW_, b_] = Table[NL + (1 - b) (cs + (1 - pR) (P + pW ED)) + b ED, {b, 0, 1, 
binc}]; 
    PCP[cs_, cc_, ED_, P_, NL_, pR_, pW_, b_] = Table[(1 - b) cs + 
b cc + (1 - (1 - b) pR) (P + (b + (1 - b) pW) ED), {b, 0, 1, 
binc}]; 
    EDD[cs_, cc_, ED_, P_, NL_, pR_, pW_, b_] = Table[ED, {b, 0, 1, binc}];

    For[i = 2, i < 20, i++, V[i_Integer] := V[i] = Min /@ Transpose[{Table[(1 - b) cs + b cc + (1 - (1 - b) pR), {b, 0, 1, 
      binc}]*V[i - 1], PCP[cs, cc, ED, P, NL, pR, pW, b], 
   NU[cs, cc, ED, P, NL, pR, pW, b], 
   EDD[cs, cc, ED, P, NL, pR, pW, b]}]];
    W[cs_, cc_, ED_, P_, NL_, pR_, pW_, b_] = Table[(1 - b) cs + b cc + (1 - (1 - b) pR), {b, 0, 1, binc}]*V[i];
    VAll[cs_, cc_, ED_, P_, NL_, pR_, pW_, b_] = 
     Transpose[{W[cs, cc, ED, P, NL, pR, pW, b], 
    PCP[cs, cc, ED, P, NL, pR, pW, b], 
    EDD[cs, cc, ED, P, NL, pR, pW, b], 
    NU[cs, cc, ED, P, NL, pR, pW, b]}];
    OptV[cs_, cc_, ED_, P_, NL_, pR_, pW_, b_] = 
     With[{m = Min@#}, {m, Position[#, m][[1, 1]]}] & /@ 
      VAll[cs, cc, ED, P, NL, pR, pW, b];
     With[{cs = 1, cc = 10, ED = 100, P = 25, NL = 5, pR = 0.1, pW = 0.25},
     MatrixForm[VAll[cs, cc, ED, P, NL, pR, pW, b]]]
      With[{cs = 1, cc = 10, ED = 100, P = 25, NL = 5, pR = 0.1, pW = 0.25},
      MatrixForm[OptV[cs, cc, ED, P, NL, pR, pW, b]]]
```

Comment: I presume the `ai` in the first two functions was meant as multiplication?

Comment: Hi, yes it is multiplication, but please do not worry about the particular function written there. I am simply trying an example here a simple one.

Comment: `With[{m = Min@#}, {m, Position[#, m][[1, 1]]}] & /@ Opt[...]`  if only 1 minimum is expected per row, `With[{m = Min@#}, {m, Position[#, m]}] & /@ Opt[...]` if multiple minimums can be in a row, in which case the vector of positions results. If the array is going to be huge, there are more efficient ways...

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you very much. And yes this will be a huge matrix most probably 1000 by 1000.

Comment: 1k x 1k is not all that big, so performance s/b fine with the above. Give it a whirl, if you need faster, comment...

Comment: I wrote the code above I am having trouble getting the minimum per row and its column index of the VAll matrix. You can run the code above and  see what I mean.

Comment: Change definition of `OptV` to `SetDelayed` (`:=` instead of `=`) - I'm guessing a typo...

Comment: Oh, yeah thanks! What is the catch about that though?

Comment: With `Set`, the map over `VAll` happens immediately, resulting in an array that's junk (because `VAll` gets called with the symbols unset, resulting in trash), and when called later, the arguments fill in their spots in that trash, but the result is nonsense...

Answer (score 2):

You have your matrix,

```
mat = 
 With[{cs = 1, cc = 10, ED = 100, P = 25, NL = 5, pR = 0.1, 
   pW = 0.25}, VAll[cs, cc, ED, P, NL, pR, pW, b]]
(* {{87.4, 46., 100, 51.}, {229.896, 62.6, 100, 61.8}, {402.204,
   79.8, 100, 72.6}, {613.824, 97.6, 100, 83.4}, {864.756, 116., 100, 
  94.2}, {1100., 135., 100, 105.}} *)
```

You can get the list you want using [`Min`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Min.html), [`First`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html), and [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html),

```
{Min@#, First@Ordering[#, 1]} & /@ mat
(* {{46., 2}, {61.8, 4}, {72.6, 4}, {83.4, 4}, {94.2, 4}, {100, 
  3}} *)
```

You could make it slightly more efficient by using using `With` to avoid calling `Min`, but on a test matrix with over 400 million elements I got a speedup of less than .2 seconds.

Of course, this assumes that you only are interested to have a single column position for each row - so if the minimum value appears more than once you get the column number of its first appearance.  From the OP it sounds like this is what is wanted.

Comment: If you're going to assume that there's only one minimum per row (and/or only care about first found, as it appears in OP), `With[{o = First@Ordering[#, 1]}, {#[[o]], o}] &` is much more efficient, particularly on large arrays...

Comment: @ciao - Thanks, that really does speed it up!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you may want to try this,

```
k[a_, i_] := Position[opt[a, i], Min[opt[a, i]]] // Flatten
```

However, in your example the minimum will always be the upper leftmost element of your final array, Opt[a,i].

I would also advise using different symbols.  Personally I avoid capitol letters generally and symbols that could conflict with Mathematica's built-in definitions.

Comment: This did not work

Comment: Could you check my code above? I edited my post now you can see the functions.

Comment: What went wrong?  My code was designed to return the row and column indices of the minimal element(s).  Maybe that's not what you want?

You can also find the minimal values themselves by the following code,

    mm[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ k[a,i]

Comment: I ran your first block of code and tested it the following code Position[test, Min[test]] // Flatten, where test is the matrix VAll evaluated at the values you specified. It gives the minimum at position {1,2}. test[[1,2]]=46 which, upon inspection of the matrix elements is correct. Again, maybe you are looking for something different than this?

Comment: Okay, try this--a modification of your code,

OptV= With[{cs = 1, cc = 10, ED = 100, P = 25, NL = 5, pR = 0.1, 
   pW = 0.25}, {#, Position[#, Min@#][[1, 1]]} & /@ 
   VAll[cs, cc, ED, P, NL, pR, pW, b]]

This produces a list of each row and the position within that row of the minimal element.